# How to generate commit ID when download zipped sources from GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using GitLab Community Edition. I can download zipped sources by commits or tags or from the release page via GitLab web interface. I'd like to have a file containing a commit ID or a tag name when I downloading sources as a zip archive from GitLab. Is there an automated way to generate such file?

I've already had a file with "`$Format:%h`" variable which is replaced with a commit ID when running "`git archive`" command. However it doesn't work for downloaded zip archives. And also it seems like it doesn't work with tag names. UPD: And it seems like it doesn't work for the [file archive API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive)

Answer (score 0):

The [file archive API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive).

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
    "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive"
```

You can even choose the from whatever format you'd like between `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2`, `tbz`, `tbz2`, `tb2`, `bz2`, `tar`, and `zip`.

You can specify a specific SHA to download as well (the SHA can be retrieved from tag information, too).

There is no first-party feature to place a file in the downloaded bundle. However, you can always create this file in the archive after you download it.

Comment: It just downloads a source package. It doesn't substitute "$Format..." strings as "git archive" command does. I need a commit ID generated inside the archive. What am I doing wrong?